# Sql Server 2019 (Fedora 32) - Msg 22022, Level 16, State 1, Line 0 SQLServerAgent is not currently running so it cannot be notified of this action

Tags: linux, fedora, sql-server-agent, sp-send-dbmail, sql-server-2019

I am getting this error. Though Agent seems to be running I have checked running state by calling

```
EXEC xp_servicecontrol 'querystate', 'SQLSERVERAGENT'
```

And it shows "Stopped." Then I call

```
EXEC xp_servicecontrol N'START',N'SQLServerAGENT';
```

And it shows "Running." After that I try executing the job by calling

```
EXEC dbo.sp_start_job N'SendCollectionSummaryReport' ;
```

And I get the Error: **SQLServerAgent is not currently running so it cannot be notified of this action.**

Then I called again `EXEC xp_servicecontrol 'querystate', 'SQLSERVERAGENT'` 
And it shows "Stopped."

I realized that something is causing failure to start SQLServerAgent. Environment details below:

Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU4) (KB4548597) - 15.0.4033.1 (X64)- Developer Edition (64-bit) ort n Linux (Fedora 32 (Workstation Edition))

[Access same server using SSME on Windows Client Machine and All Options coming Disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tq3uw.png)